# Android Location service working only after maps loaded

Tags: android, android-emulator, geolocation

I am running android studio and its emulator with API 23. I am using a location manager and the object location to obtain the current position of a user and eventually update it. I am sending positions using the device monitor or telnet and then geofix command. 
The application is able to retrieve a not-null position or an updated one just if I load google maps application in the emulator i.e., if I need to update a position I need before to load google maps and then the application is able to access to the new one. Is someone able to help me? Thanks